# Access popupWindow to dismiss from different void

Tags: java, android, android-layout

Using Android Studio I have a popup window which loads in one method

```
...
LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater)getBaseContext().getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
View popupView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.orderup, null);
final PopupWindow popupWindow = new PopupWindow(popupView,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
...
popupWindow.showAsDropDown(findViewById(R.id.posMain), 50, -1*(height-50));
```

Once this runs there are multiple buttons the user will click to mark off the task is complete.  When that is done I want to dismiss popupWindow.  How do it tell dismiss to use popupWindow even though its in a different void method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare your popupwindow add the top of your activity

```
private PopupWindow popupWindow;
```

and than inside your method

```
popupWindow = new PopupWindow(popupView,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
```

and than to dismiss that PopupWindow you can call

```
popupWindow.dismiss(); //Dismiss PopupWindow
```

or

```
if(popupWindow != null){ popupWindow.dismiss(); } //Check if PopupWindow is active, if it is, than close it.
```